# AngularJS: Getting a "[...] is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, runtime-error

i am getting a "Base64.encode is not a function" error, but i dont know why:

The following controller "login-controller" uses a LoginService:

```
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('login-controller',
     ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'LoginService',  
     function($scope, $location, $http, LoginService) {
     ...
        if(LoginService.login($scope.user.name, $scope.user.password) == true)
        {
            $location.path('/chooseMandantAsk')
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.wrongCredentials = true;
        }
    ...
    }]);
```

The following LoginService uses a function of the Service Base64:

```
angular.module('app')
       .service('LoginService', ['$location', '$http', 'Base64', function ($http, Base64) {

    ...

this.login = function (name, password){

            user.auth= "Basic " + Base64.encode(name + ":" + password);
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = user.auth;
            $http.get(url+'/login')
                .success(function(){  
                     return true;
                 })
                .error(function(){
                    user.auth = "";
                    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
                    return false;
                });
        };

    ...

}]);
```

The Base64 service has a method named encode:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Base64', function () {


    var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

        return {
            encode: function (input) {

                ...

                return output;
            },
            decode: function (input) {

                ...

                return output;
            }
        };
 });
```

The Base64 service is found and i used the Base64.encode methode in another way before and it works.

Can someone help me please and tell me, what this error means?

BR

Matthias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the $location when you injecting your dependencies -

```
service('LoginService', ['$location', '$http', 'Base64', function ($location, $http, Base64)
```

which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t see this...:(

Answer (score 3):

Your login service declaration is missing $location dependency, should be:

```
angular.module('app')
       .service('LoginService', ['$location', '$http', 'Base64', function ($location, $http, Base64) {
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t see this...:(